# Forcing consistent format for lookup values and lookup arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have this annoying issue where I need to look up values in a column that contains both numeric and alphanumeric data. For instance:

```
1234567
P654321
7654321
V234567
```

..and so on.

This column is imported/pasted into excel, and I know from past experience that excel stores data by certain formats depending on the software that exported the data (e.g. SAS). In my above example, excel treats those with characters in them as text, and those with only numbers as numbers.

I need to know how to force the stored format of this column in excel so that I don't have to worry about this [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) failing on some and working on others. Whilst some of these appear as numeric, they are not - they should be treated as character variables. I have tried setting the format of this column as text - but this has not helped.

Comment: What does SAS stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the format to text doesn't work once the data is already there, you can use "Text to columns" functionality to change to text.

Select column of data and use

Data > Text to columns > Choose "delimited" > Next > don't set any "delimiters" (uncheck all boxes) > Next > From "column data format" select "Text" > Finish

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use lookups with either text or numeric lookup values, like

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(D2+0,$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE))
```

The first lookup will perform a text lookup (if D2 is text), and if it fails, the lookup will be performed with D2 coerced into a number using the +0 operation.

Answer (score 0):

I usually offer the following when people have data of mixed formatting where numerical material may be present as EITHER text OR numbers and no desire to clean it up. Similar in intent to `teylyn`'s approach:

(using her cells and ranges)

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(TEXT(D2,"@"),$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE))
```

in which Excel tries the lookup with a numerical input (D2) being text. If it fails, hopefully because it is numerical, not something else, it converts the input to text and tries it. Assuming the input is present in the list and this is the only tribulation tossed in, your bases are covered.

Any error would indicate some other problem exists. Usually when I offer this someone is sourcing data from the internet and the problem is really extra characters they don't see and won't remove. No other problem expected here though so...

Since any error indicates some OTHER problem, this formula offers the aid in troubleshooting of being unable to give in to the belief the text vs. number issue is still the problem. KNOWING it simply isn't helps get far enough past that to really figure it out.

Side note:  in my experience, fixing the column's format via ANY of the usual ways including the accepted answer's way, the `Paste|Special|Multiply` method, and actually editing (`F2`, then `Enter`) each and every cell after setting the format work only for maybe 90% of cases. For some reason I've not sussed out yet, a not-inconsiderable number of the cases fail. This will overcome that if it truly is only text or numerical.

That said, I will also say two other things. One is small and that is that occasionally a list has the word TRUE or FALSE in it which Excel sees as a third kind of format altogether often, even most, of the time. All, in my experience, though it doesn't necessarily affect every function and the difference might not matter in this exact situation, but I can't limit the world on this one. It sometimes that pollutes the situation and might here if the data could be amenable, or the usage in SAS could make such a result appear in it even though it could never be in the data "naturally." (Like maybe neither could ever be the name of a medical procedure in a list of such but the underlying program might use a null in that field as one or the other and the data dump might include such instead of the null. That kind of thing. Weird, but it happens.)

The second is that in my usage, my data has all been reasonably behaved and sourced. I don't really do web-scraping much, for example, and when I do use sketchy data, I'm usually bringing it in with some kind of report or pasting so it doesn't bring too many faults with it. The poster mentioned SAS as the source, so I should expect the data imported is not at all sketchy and would expect all three methods in the answers to work without any problem.